# Angular - matDatepicker not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-changedetection

I have 3 components

1. main.component.html
2. mobile-main.component.html
3. desktop-main.component.html

Based on device width i want to load different view(totally different UI) using MediaMatcher & ChangeDetectorRef

My problem is when using [matDatepicker](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) it's not working properly.
When I change orientation Desktop / Mobile UI loaded working properly, But when I click on date picker it's not popping up after changing orientation(but popping up from 2nd click onwards).

We can use chrome toggle-device-toolbar to simulate.

**main.component.html**

```html
<app-desktop-main *ngIf="!mobileQuery.matches"></app-desktop-main>
<app-mobile-main *ngIf="mobileQuery.matches"></app-mobile-main>
```

**main.component.ts**

```js
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

  _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 760px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

}
```

**mobile-main.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**mobile-main.component.ts**

```js
export class MobileMainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

constructor() {

  }

}
```

**desktop-main.component.html**

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**desktop-main.component.ts**

```js
export class DesktopMainComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

constructor() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Material datepicker has an option for touch ui. For your mobile component add touchUi for what was the dropdown element:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

I'm not sure that will help the weird behavior you are noticing, but since you are not using something that is optimized for mobile it may solve the issue.